# Проблема с включением веб-интерфейса в rabbitmq

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

Ввожу в терминал команду `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. В ответ получаю:

```
Error: Failed to initialize erlang distribution: {{shutdown,
                                                   {failed_to_start_child,
                                                    auth,
                                                    {"Error when reading ./.erlang.cookie: eacces",
                                                     [{auth,init_cookie,0,
                                                       [{file,"auth.erl"},
                                                        {line,286}]},
                                                      {auth,init,1,
                                                       [{file,"auth.erl"},
                                                        {line,140}]},
                                                      {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                                       [{file,
                                                         "gen_server.erl"},
                                                        {line,328}]},
                                                      {proc_lib,
                                                       init_p_do_apply,3,
                                                       [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},
                                                        {line,240}]}]}}},
                                                  {child,undefined,
                                                   net_sup_dynamic,
                                                   {erl_distribution,
                                                    start_link,
                                                    [['rabbitmq-cli-48',
                                                      shortnames]]},
                                                   permanent,1000,supervisor,
                                                   [erl_distribution]}}.
```

При попытке выполнить командку `rabbitmqctl status` выползает еще более страшный `json`.

В чем может быть причина ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Обязательно надо запускать все под `sudo`, иначе никак...